# Smarty Plugin for Eclipse Europa

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, smarty, eclipse-3.3

Are there any good Eclipse plugins for creating smarty templates? I am using Europa with PDT on Ubuntu (though I doubt the OS will make a difference for this).

I found [SmartyPDT](http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/), but it did not seem to install properly and some of the discussions on it seemed to suggest it was for an older version of PDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find newer version of this plugin here :
 http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/issues/detail?id=31

But I haven't installed it yet with my machine.

Answer (score 1):

When I last used PHPeclipse (you know, the original PHP tools for Eclipse) around 2 years ago, it included a Smarty editor, but it was a bit rudimentary. I don't follow PHPeclipse development anymore, so maybe it has improved in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question a few hours ago, but just came across this post.  I thought I'd link my question from here, since neither of us have answers (and your question is 2 years old).

The smartyPDT plugin linked at google code is still not up to date for the latest version.

[still need smarty syntax highlighting in Eclipse PDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575142/i-need-smarty-syntax-highlighting-in-eclipse-pdt)

Answer (score 1):

Great article about integration Eclipse Helios + PDT + Smarty http://www.ikravets.com/computers-life/programming/2010/09/27/eclipse-helios-pdt-smarty (Use translation to English on this page)

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted on the [linked-to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575142/still-need-smarty-syntax-highlighting-in-eclipse-pdt-no-accepted-answer/2756884#2756884):

> I've used both SmartyPDT and SSE*.
>
> SmartyPDT is finicky and it took some
>   time for me to get it working.
>   Unfortunately, after an OS reinstall
>   my custom jars don't work anymore, so
>   I've been using SSE.
>
> It is quite basic but better than
>   nothing.
>
> It is described in English at
>   [bar54](http://www.bar54.de/smarty-eclipse.html).
>
> Download it from [Google's translated
>   version](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhp.vector.co.jp%2Fauthors%2FVA000137%2Feclipse%2Fsmarty_editor%2Fsmarty_editor.html).
>
> *I guess this is what it's called, the page is in Japanese.