# how to set up Eclipse (say Juno) to support php Smarty

Tags: eclipse, smarty

set up Eclipse and PDT (say Juno) to support php Smarty

Than you

Comment: What have you tried already? What have you searched? A quick search gave me this StackOverflow answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2756884/545442, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870879/545442) and smartypdt google code page (http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/).